# The java.lang.Process is blocking the console

Tags: java, process, console, processbuilder

Is there a way around the java.lang.Process blocking the console?
In my case, when I execute the following code, my input is blocked in the console. So I can practically no longer enter anything. I've already tried a bit. For example, it doesn't work to start it in a new thread.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "java",
            "-Xms" + this.proxyConfiguration.getMemory() + "M",
            "-Xmx" + this.proxyConfiguration.getMemory() + "M",
            "-jar",
            new File(path).getAbsoluteFile().getPath() + "//BungeeCord.jar");
    processBuilder.directory(new File(path));
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here.  Is something trying to read from the console?   Is it the parent JVM or the child JVM?   Is something actually preventing you from typing characters at the console?

Comment: It may simply be that you need to tell the `ProcessBuilder` to redirect the input stream; see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectInput(java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect) and https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.Redirect.html